# Installing Starlink - what does this step mean?

Tags: software-installation

I've just installed Ubuntu so that I can install the Starlink astronomical data analysis tools, and I'm stuck on one of the installation steps:

"7.If not yet available, install the following packages (which are required by some of the Starlink software): 1. csh "

How do I check is "csh" is 'available'?
If it isn't, where do I get the package "csh"?
And when I have downloaded it, where should I put it? In /star-namaka/lib/ or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Ubuntu software center, and type "csh" in the search field. It will indicate a package called "Shell with C-like syntax".

Alternatively,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install csh
```

To search for a package from command line:

```
apt-cache search csh
apt-cache show csh
```